# jQuery .length or .size

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've got this function as per below:

```
$(".selectedItems").on('click', '.deleteItem', function (event) {

   $(this).parent().remove();

   if ($(this).parent('.selectedItems').children().length === 0) {
       alert('hello');
   }

});
```

in conjunction with the following html:

```
<div class="selectedItems">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="selectedItems"> 
      <div class="item">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
      </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the size is always showing up as 0 regardless and my if statement keeps on triggering, i been looking at this code for a while.. im not sure about what can be the problem.

You can find a link to the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmcbride/UpGgQ/6/

Comment: It's showing up as 0 because you're `remove()`ing the parent before the if statement.

Comment: `size` for array and `length` for elements, and you removed the elements for sure the length will be 0 , call `$(this).parent().remove();` after alert

Comment: Please can you reduce the code to a bare minimum? Remove logic that is not part of the problem and html elements that are not involved in the issue.

Comment: why the downvotes and close? it's clear what he's asking.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you should ***always use length***, `size()` is not recommended for *anything*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you have already removed the element and therefore `$(this).parent()` no longer refers to anything.

Try storing the parent first:

```
var $parent = $(this).parent(), $selItem = $(this).parents(".selectedItems");
$parent.remove();
if( $selItem.children().length === 0) {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpGgQ/8/)

Comment: hmm...i have not thought of it +1.

Answer (score 0):

change the selector like this,

```
$(this).parents('.selectedItems').children().length
```

also you are removing the parent `$(this).parent().remove();`.

change that too

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UpGgQ/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first save a count of how many items there are before you remove the item from the DOM. Otherwise the reference to the DOM is lost.

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/zXnDa/

```
$(".selectedItems").on('click', '.deleteItem', function (event) {
    var count = $(this).closest(".selectedItems").find(".item").length;
    $(this).closest(".item").remove();
    if (count == 1) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```